# How to get CPF file to QL420/QL220

Tags: zebra-printers

I have to provision over 30 QL420plus printers and I'm struggling with what I thought would be easy..

We are going to use the printers in conjunction with an in-house app we have written on Windows Mobile 6.  Basically the app sends a stream to of CPCL commands to print a label.  As the label has non-standard fonts we have created 7 CPF files that we need to put on the printer.

However the problem is that the new version of LabelVista (now called Zebra Designer v2.2.3) will not let you "Send a Font" like you could in the LabelVista that ran on Windows XP. You have to use the "Zebra Font Downloader".  This is where the problem really comes home because it will not let you add a CPF file.  You have to create a MMF file and then download it to the printer.  This creates one big file which has the various fonts in it.  This is pretty useless when the label format looks like this:

```
! 0 200 200 304 {8}
LABEL
CONTRAST 0
TONE 0
SPEED 3
PAGE-WIDTH 408
BAR-SENSE 50
COUNTRY UK
VT 7 0 280 220 {0}
VB EAN{13} 1 2 60 310 230 {9}
T Got08Bpt.cpf 0 5 3 {1}
T Got05Bpt.cpf 0 5 91 TICKET PRICE
T Got010Bpt.cpf 0 5 220 RETAIL PRICE
T Got012Bpt.cpf 0 5 240 {12}
T Got014Bpt.cpf 0 20 240 {6}
CONCAT 5 105
Got28Bpt.cpf 0 0 {10}
Got14Bpt.cpf 0 7 {11}
ENDCONCAT
FORM
PRINT
```

I need different font sizes for each text line written on the label, yet I can't download the CPF files individually to the printer.

I can't install the old verison of LabelVista becuase it won't let me install on Windows 7.  I have read the CPCL Progrmaming guide from Zebra and that's ot helpful at all. Can anyone help or my Zebra account manager is going to have a really bad day. :-)

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try the code I pasted here [Sending a font file (.cpf) to zebra Qln320 printer over WLAN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951503/sending-a-font-file-cpf-to-zebra-qln320-printer-over-wlan/13392440#13392440)
I store font files in Oracle DB, load them to Windows CE device and send'em via BT to device. The only "bad thing" in this method is that printer off after each file downloading (buy the way when you load font file via USB from LabelVista the problem the same).

To delete file from printer you can use this String.Format("! U1 do \"file.delete\" \"{0}\"\r\n", FileName.ToUpper());

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Zebra Setup Utilitites" to manage your printers. This software allows you to communicate with your printers and to configure them.