# Sending a font file (.cpf) to zebra Qln320 printer over WLAN

Tags: c#, fonts, zebra-printers

I need to send a .cpf (font type) file to a QLN 320 zebra printer over WLAN using C#.
Could anybody please help.

Thanks
Midhun

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string sFileName; //file name in DOS format (8.3)
byte[] baBody; //byte array of font file
string PacketHeader = "! CISDF\r\n{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}\r\n";
//************************
int CheckSum = 0;
foreach (byte b in baBody)
  CheckSum += b;

PacketHeader = String.Format(PacketHeader, sFileName, Convert.ToString(baBody.Length, 16).PadLeft(8, '0').ToUpper(), Convert.ToString(65536 - (CheckSum % 65536), 16).PadLeft(4, '0').ToUpper());

List<byte> list = new List<byte>();
list.AddRange(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(PacketHeader.ToCharArray()));
list.AddRange(baBody);
list.AddRange(new byte[] { 0x1B, 0x68, 0x1B, 0x68, 0x1B, 0x68, 0x1B, 0x70, 0x00 });

int PacketSize = list.Count;
byte[] tmp;
int sourceIndex = 0;

while (PacketSize / 512 >= 1)
{
  tmp = list.GetRange(sourceIndex, 512).ToArray();
  int BytesSent = bt.WriteBytesToSerialPort(tmp);
  tmp = null;
  sourceIndex += BytesSent;
  PacketSize -= BytesSent;
  Sleep(100);
}

if (PacketSize > 0)
{
  tmp = list.GetRange(sourceIndex, list.Count - sourceIndex).ToArray();
  PacketSize -= bt.WriteBytesToSerialPort(tmp);
  tmp = null;
}

list.Clear();
list = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created the .CPF file you can just send the contents of the file down to the printer and it will save the font properly.

Just open up a socket and `write` all the bytes out

Comment: Hi ,thanks for the reply .. but I have already tried this and it is printing the byte as such

Comment: is the printer in line-print mode? check 
! U1 getvar "device.languages"

Comment: Hi,Tried this and got the response as "zpl_cpcl".I am looking for something in terms of "!UTILITEIS DEL asdf.cpf PRINT" (used to delete file from printer). only thing is I want to send and save file to printer not delete. Please help on this.